# How to change favicon for Dash app (served on Nginx and Gunicorn)?

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, plotly-dash, nginx-config

I have tried everything. From putting favicon.ico in assets folder, static folder, in same directory as main.py file. Also I have tried adjusting nginx configuration in many different ways like:

```
location /favicon.ico{
        alias /root/DocToHtml/static/favicon.ico;
}

location /favicon.ico{
        alias /root/DocToHtml/assets/favicon.ico;
}
```

and so on..

It seems I can't figure out how to add custom favicon to my dash app.

EDIT: This is how my current `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dth` looks like:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <hidden_server_ip>;

        location /static {
                alias /root/DocToHtml/static;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { root /root/DocToHtml/assets; }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

and favicon.ico path is: `~/DocToHtml/assets/favicon.ico`

Comment: Is `ico` the name of the file or the name of a directory containing the file `favicon.ico`? If the latter, use `root` instead of `alias`.

Comment: Sorry It was extension of the file, I have pasted that incorrectly. Now I have edited the question.

Comment: Those should work, unless you are putting them in the wrong place or there is a conflicting `location` in your configuration. The second problem can be fixed by using the `=` operator, for example: `location = /favicon.ico { root /root/DocToHtml/assets; }` - the `alias` is unnecessary, just use `root` to point to the directory where the file is located.

Comment: I have update question to include config. This still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? What do you see in the access log and error log when you access the URL? Make sure you restart Nginx and clear the browser cache between configuration changes. Try testing using `curl -I` and use `nginx -T` to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: I mean, I have cleaned cache and restarted Nginx ans still no custom favicon up there.

Comment: Access log and error log?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a while I've gotten mine to work as follows:

I'm including this in my NGINX sites-enabled file (note the underscore before the file name):

```
    location = /_favicon.ico {
       alias /var/www/html/static/favicon.ico;
    }
```

...and dropped my favicon.ico inside /var/www/html/static, of course!

I hope this works for you too.

Comment: ```location = /favicon.ico {
       alias /var/www/html/static/favicon.ico;
    }
```
Worked for me.